# SQL is independent table allowed in a database structure?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Ok so till today I had the impression that it is okay to have an independent table in my data structure and I had a table that keeps track of failed logins coming from IPs (so I would keep track of the IPs of attempted logins and then block them if they have more than `n` attemps)

But today I was told by my professor that it is not possible/right to have this table as an independent table and it has to have a relationship with other tables otherwise its wrong.

Now I cant help but this that the table is independent simply because the purpose of it isnt to have a relationship with other entries/tables.

am I right or wrong? and please explain.

**MORE INFO**

the login attempt table is filled when a user tries to login but fails. and its primarily dependent on the IP of the user, so if a user fails to get the right password `n` times there will be `n` entries in the table and the access would be blocked for `x` minutes. This is the purpose of the table, but somehow my ERD was criticized my professor for having a table standing alone (and I was told " I have never seen a table stand ALONE in all the years I have worked in this field ") and I still wasnt sure if he is right. Here is the table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login_attempts` (
  `ip` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attempts` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `lastlogin` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and somehow eventhough he couldnt really explain how, he wanted me to connect this to the user table. now is this wrong?

Comment: If you store logins (userids, usernames - however you call it) you probably have a relation to your users table unless you also log failed logins for unknown users (e.g. a typo in the username)

Comment: The only way I can think of doing this, and it is entirely superfluous, is to add a PK to the login attempt table and then add a linking table between login attempt and user. The linking table would only hold records for login attempts that were successful. However, this is unnecessary if you don't have the requirement of tracking this data. On the other hand, it might satiate your professor.

Comment: As you apparently store only the IP of the user's computer but not the userid itself I cannot see how you can create a foreign key to any other table in your system)

Comment: well thanks for the comments, but as far as my structure goes, there is absolutely nothing wrong with it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with having a table that has no related tables is none exist in the data you want to store.

However in the case above, I believe that you should store the username and password attempted in the Login_attempts table. Then have a linking table to join to the table where the username is stored. This way you can see easily if a particular login name appears to be compromised (you are getting thousands of attempts using it and from mulitple ips) so the person can be wrned to change it. You can also identify those IPs that are trying bogus usersnames as well as those that do not appear to know th correct paasword. This may help a great deal in finding certain IPs you want to ban from attempting to log in to your system.  The connection to the actual users can help you see if the bad tries are coming from differnt IP addresses than the good logins.

Comment: thanks that helped a lot. I'm gna actually make the features u mentioned on top... They seem cool..

Answer (score 2):

A database certainly can have a table with no relation to any other table.  Likely your professor was just saying that this is not how he wishes you to implement your particular assignment.

If you post details of the assignment, we might be able to advise further, but it may be that only your professor can really clarify this.

If, as it appears, your professor wants you to link it to the users table, you need to add a column and a foreign key constraint linking the login_attempts table to your users table.

For help with doing that, you should have a look at the mysql documentation on [Foreign Key Constraints in InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) (as you appear to be using InnoDB).

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of the requirement that all tables in a schema must be somehow related to another table. What does your schema look like? Perhaps there was another problem with it.

Comment: I have updated the question. Let me know if you still need more info

Answer (score 1):

A minimal table for failed logins by IP address would have just two columns: ip address and a timestamp.  In practice, you might need to use different datatypes, depending mainly on the resolution of your timestamp.

```
create table failed_logins (
  ip_address inet not null,
  failed_at timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
  primary key (ip_address, failed_at)
);
```

A table like that would be "all key", and it would be in 5NF. It has no relationship to other tables.

Now, if you got this table into 5NF by decomposing tables that were in a lower normal form, you *would* have some tables you *could* relate your failed logins table to. But I see none of these in your description.